# How do I save char to my 2d array using fread?

Tags: c

```
char *arr[512][lineCount];
while(lineCount > 0){       
    char *savedLine = malloc(512);
    while(1){
    fread(savedLine, 1, 1,fd);
    if(savedLine != '\n'){
        arr = savedLine;
    }else{
        break;
    }
    }lineCount --;
}
```

So I'm trying to create a 2D char array that stores characters line by line.
I am not allowed to use fgets so I used fread to store one char at a time until it reaches `'\n'`. But it won't compile saying I can't compare pointer and integer (`savedLine != 'n'`) and array type is not assignable(`char *arr[512][lineCount]`). rest of the variables are declared in my code.

Comment: Those dimensions look especially messed up. That shouldn't be an array of array of pointer to char. If anything it should be a VLA of pointer to char. I.e., I'd start by changing `char *arr[512][lineCount];` to `char *arr[lineCount];`. I'd also have an ascending counter, starting at zero to index `arr` while building your list. Finally, [fgets](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) is probably more appropriate for per-line work.

Comment: Enable compiler warnings.`savedLine != '\n'` should warn as well as others:  Comparing a pointer to a character constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have a 2D array of characters, you have a 2D array of pointers, and you never assign anything to those pointers. But you don't need pointers at all. Just declare a `char` variable and read into its address, then copy it into the array.

```
char arr[lineCount][512];
int pos = 0;
while (lineCount > 0) {
    char tempChar;
    size_t n = fread(&tempChar, 1, 1, fd);
    if (n == 0) { // EOF or error
        break;
    }
    if (tempChar == '\n') {
        arr[lineCount-1][pos] = '\0'; // Add trailing null to current line
        lineCount--; // Start new line
        pos = 0;
    } else {
        arr[lineCount-1][pos] = tempChar;
        pos++;
        if (pos == 511) { // Filled up current line, start new line
            arr[lineCount-1][pos] = '\0';
            lineCount--;
            pos = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Notice that you need to subtract 1 from `lineCount` when assigning to the array, because arrays are indexed from 0 to `size-1`. Also notice that you had the declaration of the array backwards.

Comment: The amount used of each `arr[]` is not recorded.  Maybe a `'\0'` on end-if-line, EOF?

Comment: @chux Thanks, fixed that.